# What is the optimal way to launch multiple coroutines

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Launching coroutines can be done in different ways.
One example can be to have multiple launch inside a scope.
See the code below

```
suspend fun main() {
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
val job1 = scope.launch {
    launch {
        println("job1 launch")
        delay(100)
    }
    launch {
        println("job2 launch")
        delay(100)
    }
}

job1.join()
```

}

Another way is to use the scope multiple times and launch it like in the code below

```
suspend fun main() {
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
val job1 = scope.launch {
    println("scope1 launch")
    delay(50)
}
val job2 = scope.launch {
    println("scope2 launch")
    delay(50)
}
job1.join()
job2.join()
```

}

Which is the optimal way to launch multiple coroutines. For me it is not clear at all if there are any difference in those two ways

Answer (score 2):

The way `coroutines` are launched does not have a significant impact on performance or efficiency. The best choice varies based on your application's logical structure and requirements.

If there's a parent-child relationship or dependency between `coroutines` and you want them all to be canceled together in case of failure, the nested launches approach (1st) may be more appropriate. It enables you to group related coroutines into a parent launch.

The 2nd approach could be the better choice if the `coroutines` can run independently without dependencies. It permits launching them one by one and managing each one separately.